# Как исправить разную позицию у псевдоэлементов, CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, псевдоэлемент

Есть три одинаковых блока, с текстом. Текст представлен псевдоэлементом и повернут на 90 градусов. Но почему-то каждый элемент после первого смещен, как это исправить. Ниже ссылка для наглядного примера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://plupiks.github.io/project2/

```css
.benefits--blocks {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
  }
}

.blocks--img {
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.blocks--text {
  position: relative;
  width: 540px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    background: #2e77e4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
  }
}

.blocks-text-before::before {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  content: attr(data-rotate-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: -95px;
  font-family: 'CormorantInfant';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 56px;
  line-height: 135%;
  color: #a4c7fc;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.blocks-text--title {
  font-family: 'CormorantInfant';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 56px;
  line-height: 135%;
  color: #2e77e4;
}

.benefits--blocks {
  &:nth-child(odd) {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<article class="benefits--blocks blocks">
        <div class="blocks--img">
          <img src="@img/1920/benefits/01.png" alt="benefits image">
        </div>
        <div class="blocks--text blocks-text-before" data-rotate-text="Расскажу">
          <h3 class="blocks-text--title">
            Практикам, экспертам, специалистам
          </h3>
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="list-item">
              Не понимаете, в чем ваша ценность как эксперта и мучаетесь от синдрома самозванца
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
              Хотите передавать свой опыт, но не понимаете, как начать
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
              Желаете перейти из офлайна в онлайн
            </li>
            <li class="list-item">
              Мечтаете о своём курсе, но не знаете, с кем и как мне это делать
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно как нужно правильно. Нужно повернутый текст левее? Или расстояние чтобы не было между строками?

Comment: нет, там есть несколько одинаковых блоков, у все у них есть этот псевдоэлемент, он уже повернут правильно, но все псевдоэлементы в блоках после первого смещены в сторону почему-то. Они смещаються из-за длины текста, вот как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608838/how-to-rotate-text-and-position-it-properly-css-html

Answer (score 0):

Да [@Vitaliy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/467585/vitaliy) ты прав это из-за длинны текста, тк ты позиционируешь слева, но при этом поворачиваешь на 90deg

```
.blocks-text-before::before {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    content: attr(data-rotate-text);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -70px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: "CormorantInfant";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 56px;
    line-height: 135%;
    color: #a4c7fc;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: left center;
}
```

Можно попробовать так)

Comment: я добавил width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1; и вроде как работает нормально)